# How to run a function if the parent event has been running for longer than a period of time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, settimeout, html5-audio

I have an audio event that in the buffering is not loading quickly, i want to change some events.

so in audio, if the event 'waiting' is triggered do nothing unless it takes more than 5 seconds. Then run function X.

Here is a sample code:

```
$(audio).on("waiting", function () {
    // RUN AFTER 5 SECONDS
    console.log("This is taking way too long! Lets panic..");
    $play.append('<div class="icon-loading"></div>');
});

$(audio).on("playing", function () { 
    // This is the function that runs after wait is over
    console.log("Wait is over, it is loaded!");
    $play.append('<span class="icon-play-button"></span>');
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so you'll want a setTimeout which is cleared if *some other event* is fired indicating the wait is over - do you know what event indicates this?

Comment: @JaromandaX just updated code. Basically if there is no timeout, then the `waiting` event triggers every seconds as it is loading the media and runs its functions inside it (css style etc). but i want it to wait few seconds before it changes the icons etc...

Comment: I understood the question, I just made a suggestion to how you could achieve your goal - so, my suggestion obviously didn't help, so I've posted an answer instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use setTimeout and clearTimeout as follows

```
let waitingTimeout;
$(audio).on("waiting", function() {
  // RUN AFTER 5 SECONDS
  waitingTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("This is taking way too long! Lets panic..");
    $play.append('<div class="icon-loading"></div>');
  }, 5000);
});

$(audio).on("playing", function() {
  if (waitingTimeout) {
    clearTimeout(waitingTimeout);
    waitingTimeout = null;
  }
  // This is the function that runs after wait is over
  console.log("Wait is over, it is loaded!");
  $play.append('<span class="icon-play-button"></span>');
});
```